# Saving xmlns into a variable

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I want to save the "mis20" into a new variable

xmlns:mis20="http://www.mis.sfm.se/mis20"

the mis20 after xmlns:

See the thick text:

"<"mis20:mislife version="mislife00" xmlns:**mis20**="http://www.mis.sfm.se/mis20" xmlns:mis2Util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/userCSharp"">"

Comment: as with the last time you asked: this is an xml namespace alias declaration; it has a **very specific meaning**, i.e. it defines what `mis20:` means in `mis20:mislife`. What **exactly** is it that you're trying to do? you're asking very vague questions that seem to suggest you're not really sure what these nuances of xml mean. That's fine - I can respect that. But: you need to take a step back and tell us what you're *actually trying to do*, rather than talking about how you're trying to do it. That way, we can probably help you.

Comment: in particular: it *doesn't really make sense* to query the name of an alias - outside of the document parser, it **doesn't exist** - only the actual namespace (`http://www.mis.sfm.se/mis20`) is relevant. If you're writing XPath, it is the namespace, not the alias in the original document, that you need. You can *use* aliases with XPath, but the aliases are *contextual to the call-site*, and can be completely different in the usage vs the original document. For example, if I declare `foo` to be an alias for `http://www.mis.sfm.se/mis20`, then `foo:mislife` would work just fine.

Comment: As the namespace is adding the "mis20:" infront of each element my normal search for that element isn't working.                                                                    So as of now i'm searching for "var numberList=doc.GetElementsByTagName("number");
            foreach (XmlNode number in numberList)"                                                                 The problem s that i need to replace the ("number") with ("mis20:number") for it to work, and i need a way to pass in the namespace as a variable like this (namespace + "number") so that it can read it.

Comment: Here's how it looks like in the xmlfile"<"mis20:number>123412340000"<"/mis20:number">"

Comment: so can I check: the question is really "how do I find all the `number` elements form the `http://www.mis.sfm.se/mis20` namespace?" (which is what `mis20:number` *means* here) - if so: fine, we can help with that; now: what API are you using, if any? `XDocument`? `XmlDocument`? something else?

Comment: okay nice! thxs for taking your time !  I'm using XmlDocument

Comment: And yes that's correct, i need to find all the number elements in the xml document.

Comment: If you're using `XmlDocument`, would `GetElementsByTagName("number")` not work? I seem to recall (although I mostly use `XDocument` these days) that `GetElementsByTagName` didn't care about namespaces...

Comment: I edited my answer to show `XmlDocument`, but without an actual example doc it is impossible for me to test it

Comment: No, i have to have GetElementsByTagName("mis20:number") for it to work. And that's where the issue is that in diffrent files there could be a diffrent namespace so for the next file this could change to lets say GetElementsByTagName("mis172:number") and so on.

Comment: then: see the `SelectNodes` example below

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is `XDocument`, what you want is something like:

```cs
XNamespace ns = "http://www.mis.sfm.se/mis20";
var numbers = doc.Descendants(ns + "number");
```

Here, the `ns + "number"` syntax creates an `XName` that is the composite of the *namespace* `"http://www.mis.sfm.se/mis20"` and *local name* `"number"`. The *alias* (`"mis20"`) doesn't matter, because the alias is just there to avoid repetition in the document. It doesn't really exist.

---

With `XmlDocument`, it should be *something like*:

```cs
var mgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
mgr.AddNamespace("foo", "http://www.mis.sfm.se/mis20"); // the actual alias doesn't matter
var numbers = doc.SelectNodes("//foo:number", mgr);
```